# Showing Plain Text of a Password TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, textbox, passwords

I am having a textbox for password field, I want to add a Checkbox that toggles the password into plain text.

I did the following coding for it.

```
txtpwd.PasswordChar = (char)(byte)32;
```

but this simply hides not showing the plain text of what is typed in textbox field.

any body can help?

Comment: I have mentioned C#. Its WinForms

Comment: WPF has some pitfals.

[According To StackOverFlowPost][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832470/wpf-font-why-are-some-characters-missing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the solution, I added CheckBox with name chkpwd and on its CheckedChange event i added this code

```
private void chkpwd_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkpwd.Checked)
            txtpwd.PasswordChar = '\0';
        else
            txtpwd.PasswordChar = '*';
    }
```

This will show plain text when checkbox's checked property true

Comment: I try to use code you provided for WPF, but when I set `txtpwd.PasswordChar = '\0'` I got [squares](http://clip2net.com/s/60Er27) inside password box. How to fix this ?

Comment: Well I didn't work with WPF. I will see.

Comment: Alezis: I have found the link by searching

Comment: what did you find? I found many links as well, but haven't seen any solution which works with `txtpwd.PasswordChar = '\0'` for WPF. Please share your link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832470/wpf-font-why-are-some-characters-missing

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832470/wpf-font-why-are-some-characters-missing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1108878/1147352

Comment: Only if UseSystemPassword is false. This doesn't work if it's true.